# Installing Rails Plugin Requires Git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Installing rails plugins from github requires git in the system?
OS is linux. Is it possible to install plugin without git installation in the local system.

Comment: btw: I love installing plugins from github and if you'll use more than just a handful plugins it's sure not a bad idea to install git as well. It makes things easier! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Sure!

1. download the plugin from github as *.tar.gz
2. uncompress and copy it to your vendor/plugins folder
3. run the install tasks if necassary

Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 0):

OR just install git-core on your linux system :)

If using Ubuntu or Debian

```
 sudo apt-get install git-core
```

HTH