# Installing Git on a Debian Lenny server

Tags: git, debian, lenny

*Sorry in advance if there's already an answer for this somewhere in the world, but I'm already 3h trying to install this in my PRODUCTION server, and I'm not getting anywhere.*

**My needs:**

---

I  want to run git commands (eg.: push, commit, etc) on my server. In order to do that, I need the "git" command (duh!).

**What I tried:**

---

Tried to follow this: http://oli.zilla.org.uk/2010/12/07/installing-git-on-debian-lenny.html

And this: [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide#323764)

And this: [Installing Rails Plugin Requires Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414454/installing-rails-plugin-requires-git)

Tried to download the source (http://packages.debian.org/lenny/i386/git-core/download), the .deb file (http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/git/)

**Problems:**

---

404 when trying to get the source: http://packages.debian.org/lenny/i386/git-core/download

All the repositories I've tried to use gave me a 404 when downloading the packages

Need to update the libc6 from 2.7 to 2.9 in order to install the git-1.7.9 as seen in:

```
stewie:/tmp# dpkg -i git_1.7.9-1~bpo60+1_i386.deb 
Selecting previously deselected package git.
(Reading database ... 20477 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking git (from git_1.7.9-1~bpo60+1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git:
 git depends on libc6 (>= 2.9); however:
  Version of libc6 on system is 2.7-18lenny7.
 git depends on libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2-1); however:
  Package libcurl3-gnutls is not installed.
 git depends on libexpat1 (>= 1.95.8); however:
  Package libexpat1 is not installed.
 git depends on liberror-perl; however:
  Package liberror-perl is not installed.
 git depends on git-man (>> 1:1.7.9); however:
  Package git-man is not installed.
 git depends on git-man (<< 1:1.7.9-.); however:
  Package git-man is not installed.
dpkg: error processing git (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 git
```

but couldn't find the 2.9 for Debian lenny

---

**Final question:**

**How do I install git on my Debian 5 (lenny) ?**

---

**Tries**

Tried @sarnold solution, but (more 404s): http://justpaste.it/w5s

---

---

**Solution:**

Used @sarnold's comment (in his own answer)!

> Ah. Lenny has been removed from the mirrors. You need to edit your sources.list to use archive.debian.org instead -- for all your package lines, not just this new one. Please consider upgrading this system to a supported release.

How to:

Edit the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib

deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main non-free contrib
```

Update apt-get cache:

```
apt-get update
```

Install git:

```
apt-get install git-core
```

Done! :)

*Late edit:*

For some reason, it seems that the Deutsch mirror still valid. Just add

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ lenny main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ lenny main
```

to your sources.list and try to get the package.

Or, of course, try the Debian backports:

```
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main
```

Comment: I don't know about Debian Lenny, but ... `wget http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.9.6.tar.gz && tar -xzf git-1.7.9.6.tar.gz && cd git-1.7.9.6 && make && sudo make install`

Comment: Is there not a package in the default apt sources?

Comment: .. with the slight caveat that the `su && make install` can't be run exactly as typed.

Comment: Tried @JamesMcLaughlin's solution, but:
GITGUI_VERSION = 0.16.0
    * new locations or Tcl/Tk interpreter
    GEN git-gui
    INDEX lib/
    * tclsh failed; using unoptimized loading
    MSGFMT    po/de.msg make[1]: *** [po/de.msg] Error 127
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Thank you; `apt-get install git-core` works. All these responses about installing from source are missing the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [Lenny is no longer supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_history), I strongly recommend migrating this machine (or services) to a newer release. At the very least, severely firewall this machine and restrict access to it to only the most trusted of your users -- without security updates, a newly discovered remote compromise or local privilege escalation could give you far more trouble than upgrading.

That said, the [backports project](http://backports-master.debian.org/) provides newer builds of packages for older systems. You can [add the required `deb` line to your `apt` `sources.list` file](http://backports-master.debian.org/Instructions/) -- I'm going to guess it looks something like this:

```
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main
```

then run

```
apt-get update
apt-get -u -t lenny-backports install git-all
```

(I'm taking the `git-all` package name from a [packages.debian.org lookup](http://packages.debian.org/lenny-backports/git-all), which shows it is available for `lenny-backports`.)

The `-t` *pins* that package to that release. It's not something you'd use every day, but the one time you need it, it is worth its weight in saffron.

Comment: Ah. Lenny has been removed from the mirrors. You need to edit your `sources.list` to use [`archive.debian.org`](http://www.debian.org/distrib/archive) instead -- for **all** your package lines, not just this new one. **Please** consider upgrading this system to a supported release.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install the debian backports repository (it won't update from there unless you explicitly ask it to):

   ```
   # echo 'deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main'\
          >> /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Install git:

   ```
   apt-get -t lenny-backports install git-core
   ```

where the `-t lenny-backports` tells it explicitly to look for git in backports.

See [this](http://backports-master.debian.org/Instructions/) site.

Also, the above directions were edited and really taken from the directions for squeeze backports, although I believe they work. I don't know if this is an option on a production server, but I guess Debian is not providing much support for lenny anymore, according to [this](http://backports-master.debian.org/news/lenny_backports_discontinued/):

> lenny backports discontinued
>
> Following the normal Debian Archive lenny-backports is now
>   discontinued. That means that no upload will be possible anymore and
>   lenny-backports(-sloppy) get moved to archive.debian.org. If you
>   haven't updated yet - now is the time to move to squeeze.
>
> Some numbers about lenny-backports and lenny-backports-sloppy:
>
> ```
> Source packages: lenny-backports: 667 - sloppy: 21
> Uploads: lenny-backports: 1445 - sloppy: 51
> Contributors: lenny-backports: 146 - sloppy: 17
> ```
>
> Without all those contributors lenny-backports wouldn't have been
>   possible. Thank you very much for your support! Posted Sun Mar 25
>   09:07:14 2012

Comment: Why did you make this `Community Wiki`? You put good effort into writing a good answer and should get reputation for it. (Normally I'd just flag for moderator attention and ask them to reset it, but since you mentioned it explicitly in the changelog, I'm very surprised.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Did you write that for me? I have no idea why it's set to Community Wiki...

Comment: yea, didn't know that's what 'community wiki' meant. oh, well :)

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me (git clone https:// ... would failed with tls error) :

- manually compile and re-install newer libcurl3-gnutls and git from source

Debian Lenny ; standard version libcurl3-gnutls 7.18.2-8lenny6 has a bug with http/https behind a proxy.

**first : libcurl3-gnutls :**

- # wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.21.0.orig.tar.gz
- # tar zxvf curl_7.21.0.orig.tar.gz
- # cd curl-7.21.0/
- # ./configure make
- # make install

**then : git :**

- if needed : remove previous git : # apt-get remove --purge git git-core
- # wget  ..........  git-1.9.0.tar.gz
- # tar -zxf git-1.9.0.tar.gz
- # cd git-1.9.0
- # make prefix=/usr/local install

**refresh bash cache (if needed)**

- $ type git
- $ hash -r

**and ... test :**

- $ git ls-remote --heads https://  [github] /jeromerobert/jCAE.git
- $ git clone  https:// [github] ... flask-sphinx-themes.git

Hope it helps.

Cavaliba.

Answer (score 1):

### My solution:

- EDIT /etc/apt/sources.list:

  ```
  deb http://archive.debian.org/debian            lenny            main non-free contrib
  deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security   lenny/updates    main non-free contrib
  deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports  lenny-backports  main
  ```
- apt-get update
- apt-get install -t lenny-backports git-core --no-install-recommends